# Drupal Coding D7 - Taxonomy - How do I establish the hierarchy and associated fields for taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Reviewing the code in Taxonomy.module I determined the array to define a taxonomy terms as:

```
 'taxonomy_term' => array(
      'label' => t('Taxonomy term'),
      'controller class' => 'TaxonomyTermController',
      'base table' => 'taxonomy_term_data',
      'uri callback' => 'taxonomy_term_uri',
      'fieldable' => TRUE,
      'entity keys' => array(
        'id' => 'tid',
        'bundle' => 'vocabulary_machine_name',
        'label' => 'name',
      ),
      'bundle keys' => array(
        'bundle' => 'machine_name',
      ),
      'bundles' => array(),
      'view modes' => array(
        // @todo View mode for display as a field (when attached to nodes etc).
        'full' => array(
          'label' => t('Taxonomy term page'),
          'custom settings' => FALSE,
```

Assigning the correct info in the array and calling `taxonomy_save_term($term);` creates the term, but I have not unearthed the method or array fields necessary to define the hierarchy and attach data fields.

Are there additional array key/values to identify the parent/children and fields?

Are the fields attached to a term in a separate operation after the term is created?

What array keys are required to create the term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A taxonomy term is an entity in Drupal 7 so adding field data is exactly the same as adding it to a node, e.g.

```
$term = new stdClass;
$term->name = 'Term Name';
$term->vid = $vocab_id;
$term->field_some_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'A value';
taxonomy_term_save($term);
```

The hierarchy is handled separately to this, in the [`taxonomy_term_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7) function. All you need to do is add the parent term ID (`tid`) to the `$term` object before you save it, like so:

```
$term->parent = $parent_tid;
```

For multiple parents you would pass an array instead:

```
$term->parent = array($parent_tid_1, $parent_tid_2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
// create the Foo vocabulary
$vocabulary = new stdClass();
$vocabulary->name = "Foo Name";
$vocabulary->machine_name = "foo_vocab";
$vocabulary->description = "Foo Description";
taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocabulary);
// annoyingly taxonomy_vocabulary_save doesn't return any information about the vocabulary
$voc_vid = db_query("SELECT v.vid FROM {taxonomy_vocabulary} v WHERE v.machine_name = 'foo_vocab'")->fetchField();
$terms = array(
  'bar',
  'bat',
);
foreach ($terms as $term_name) {
  $term = new stdClass();
  $term->vid = $voc_vid;
  $term->name = $term_name;
  taxonomy_term_save($term);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not address the issue of term hierarchy or fields.